# How to show string data in tooltip using n3-charts with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, n3-charts

I need to show some text data in my chart using n3-charts. 
For example, this is my data object:

```
[{x: new Date(X,X,X), stopNum:stopNumber, stopsName:stopName, edge:tolerance, satsView:satsVal, satsUse:satsUseVal},
{x: new Date(X,X,X), stopNum:stopNumber, stopsName:stopName, edge:tolerance, satsView:satsVal, satsUse:satsUseVal},
{x: new Date(X,X,X), stopNum:stopNumber, stopsName:stopName, edge:tolerance, satsView:satsVal, satsUse:satsUseVal}]
```

What I need is to show the name of Bus Stop into tooltip which shows up after mouse hover.

I tried to use the options like tooltip formatter, tooltipHook and some other things but nothing works. 
Can you recommend me somethig which can help me to resolve this problem?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tooltipHook to adjust tooltip format and its content

```
tooltipHook: function(d){
  if (d) {
    return {
      rows:  d.map(function(s){
      })
    }
  }
}
```